# The 'is copy' trait drops the type of Array objects

Tags: raku

Please consider this code:

```
sub c1(Complex @a)         { say @a.WHAT }
sub c2(Complex @a is copy) { say @a.WHAT }

my Complex @a = 1+2i, 2+3i, 4+2i;
c1(@a); # prints (Array[Complex])
c2(@a); # prints (Array)
```

Is this a bug or the expected behavior?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a bug.  Please create an issue for this.  Thank you!

Comment: Hmm... looks like this is buried somewhere deep in argument binding :-(